# The meaning of "troph" as in heterotroph or trophy?

Tags: meaning, etymology

What does "troph" mean when we break down words, and where does it originate?

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done
. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the greek **trophe'**  [entymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=trophe)

> "of or pertaining to nutrition, food, or nourishment," 1856, from
>   Greek trophikos, from trophe "nourishment, food" (see -trophy).

**trophic** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/trophic)

> 1. Of or relating to nutrition.

and

**heterotroph**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/heterotrophhttp://)

> An organism that is dependent on complex organic substances for
>   nutrition because it cannot synthesize its own food

and

**trophy**